# consumer protection in obtaining legal documents from a car dealer

Tags: contract-law

I am 85 years old and recently purchased a Frontier Truck from Nissan World Car.
The truck is a 2019 and was damaged on the hood and top of the truck, however, in good faith I agreed to purchase it providing the vehicle would be fixed.  I took the vehicle  back to the dealer and they provided me with a loner.. They took 3 weeks to order a new hood and replace it.  On Sept 8 I picked up the truck, Saturday and Sunday I noticed a dent on the top of the truck and went back to the dealer and the service department said they could not do anything until the salesman made an order.   The salesman came out to view the damage and he said that I might have been hit by a rock of something.  I told him it was not damaged when I 
dropped it off and he said he would call me back bu hasn't to date.  I kept trying because all my vehicle documents were missing, they claim the papers were not in the loner or the truck and I get no response from the dealer.  I do not feel that I should be treated this way and only want the truck fixed and a copy of my contract given to me.  Also I had purchased a 2019 Nissan Sentry in Feb and returned it back for the 2019 Frontier because the car was too low.  I know owe $37,000 dollars.  Whatever help you could give would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: What are you looking for help in? Getting the truck fixed?

Comment: What city/state do you live in? We need to know for relevant consumer laws.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page.  You can see the link at the bottom of the page.